# How do I determine the language setting of a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I gather this setting is taken from the Document Settings dialog. But I can't find anything relevant to this in the App Services documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSpreadsheetLocale` should do the trick

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetLocale()

Comment: I see! You extract the 1st 2 characters of the locale and use that as the language abbreviation! A little obtuse but effective. Thanx!